# How do I use cut to make tab the delimiter?

Tags: command-line

I am working with the egrep command and I need to pair with the cut (and ONLY cut) command to change a ":" into a tab. For example change:

```
Blahblahblah:2000
```

to:

```
Blahblahblah    2000
```

I currently have this, but it turns the ":" into "/t" and not tab:

```
egrep -e "^[0-9]" *.txt | cut -d ":" --output-delimiter="/t" -f 1- > test.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```bash
egrep -e "^[0-9]" *.txt | cut -d ":" --output-delimiter=$'\t' -f 1- > test.txt
```

should work in Bash.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I checked the man page for cut and I didn't see anywhere that explained what "$" does. Could you please explain that bit to me?

Comment: @gbrooks: It's not actually 'cut', it's Bash. Bash expands the backslash escapes in strings like `$'..'` and only strings like that. '\t' is standard escape for a tab.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. I just ran the command noticed I got twice as many lines as I should have (as noted by the assignment this is for). Without going too much off topic, does the fact that it uses Bash cause this?

Comment: @gbrooks: Shouldn't cause any problems using Bash. You may ask a new question, however.

Answer (score -1):

Alternately, you can also use the `tr` command, if your need is to just replace the delimiter as follows

```
echo "Blahblahblah:2000" | tr ':' '\t'
```

You will get the following output

```
Blahblahblah    2000
```

Comment: From the question: "... cut (and ONLY cut) command ..."